# MVVM LiveData and DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm, android-livedata

I'm working on architecture components and now i'm learning LiveData and data binding. I'm able to bind LiveData with layout for Integer values but i'm not able to find for List of Users.

This one is a working example for LiveData with data binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.tutorial3livedataanddatabinding.viewmodel.CounterViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewModel.counter)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ViewModel class and Activity

```
public class CounterViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> counter = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(MutableLiveData<Integer> counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void counterValue(int val) {
        this.counter.setValue(val);
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int mCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
            LifeCycleOwner should be set for LiveData changes to be propagated to UI for this binding
         */

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        final CounterViewModel counterViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CounterViewModel.class);

        binding.setViewModel(counterViewModel);
        increaseCounter(counterViewModel);
    }

    private void increaseCounter(final CounterViewModel counterViewModel) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCounter ++;
                counterViewModel.counterValue(mCounter);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

For the example above data binding with data works fine. Counter updates but unlike the document states it does not stop counting while app is stopped or LiveData

> Note: LiveData objects only send updates when the activity, or the
>   LifecycleOwner is active. If you navigate to a different app, the log
>   messages pause until you return. LiveData objects only consider
>   subscriptions as active when their respective lifecycle owner is
>   either STARTED or RESUMED.

My real question is how to implement Data Binding with a `LiveData<List<User>>` class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.tutorial3livedataanddatabinding2.viewmodel.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.tutorial3livedataanddatabinding2.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.getUserRecords()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.349" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_shufle"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.shuffleUsers()}"
            android:text="Shuffle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.addUser()}"
            android:text="Add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_shufle" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**android:text="@{viewModel.getUserRecords()** binds user data as String at start but it does not update when new a new user is added or list is shuffled unless device is rotated.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;

    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        // do async operation to fetch users
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Jack");
        user.setLastName("Daniels");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Johnny");
        user.setLastName("Walker");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("James");
        user.setLastName("Jameson");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Arthur");
        user.setLastName("Guinness");
        userList.add(user);

        users.setValue(userList);

    }

    public void shuffleUsers() {
        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null && users.getValue().size() > 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(users.getValue());
            // Needed to update Live Data observers
            users.setValue(users.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void addUser() {
        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("Winston");
            user.setLastName("Whiskey");

            users.getValue().add(user);
            // Needed to update Live Data observers
            users.setValue(users.getValue());

        }
    }


    public String getUserRecords() {

        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null && users.getValue().size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (User user : users.getValue()) {
                sb.append( user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        return "empty list";
    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        myViewModel.getUsers();

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setViewModel(myViewModel);
        // Required for  binding with LiveData
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I edited MyViewModel class after Blackbelt's answer
Now i'm getting      `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference`
`System.out.println()` inside `apply()` is not invoked, other 2 gets invoked and does not return **null** for `users` and `users.getValue()`

```
import android.arch.core.util.Function;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.example.tutorial3livedataanddatabinding2.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;

    public LiveData<String> userStringLiveData = Transformations.map(users, new Function<List<User>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(List<User> input) {
            System.out.println("userStringLiveData users: " + users);
            return getUserRecords();
        }
    });

    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        // do async operation to fetch users
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Jack");
        user.setLastName("Daniels");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Johnny");
        user.setLastName("Walker");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("James");
        user.setLastName("Jameson");
        userList.add(user);

        user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Arthur");
        user.setLastName("Guinness");
        userList.add(user);

        users.setValue(userList);

        System.out.println("MyViewModel users " + users);
        System.out.println("MyViewModel users List" + users.getValue());

    }

    public void shuffleUsers() {
        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null && users.getValue().size() > 0) {
            Collections.shuffle(users.getValue());
            // Needed to update Live Data observers
            users.setValue(users.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void addUser() {
        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null) {

            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("Winston");
            user.setLastName("Whiskey");

            users.getValue().add(user);
            // Needed to update Live Data observers
            users.setValue(users.getValue());

        }
    }


    public String getUserRecords() {

        if (users != null && users.getValue() != null && users.getValue().size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (User user : users.getValue()) {
                sb.append(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        return "empty list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a lot like users will be null at the moment of object creation, which is when userStringLiveData is first evaluated. So Transformations.map will be passed a null as its first parameter, rather than the LiveData you want it to operate on later.

Here's my recommendation:

```
public class r_RealTulipCoin {

  private LiveData<List<User>> users;

  public LiveData<String> userStringLiveData;

  public void onCreate() {
    getUsersLiveDataFromRoomOrSomething();
    prepareUserStringLiveData();
  }

  private void prepareUserStringLiveData() {
    userStringLiveData = Transformations.map(users, new android.arch.core.util.Function<List<User>, String>() {
          @Override
          public String apply(List<User> input) {
            System.out.println("userStringLiveData users: " + users);
            return getUserRecordsAsSingleStringFromThisParticularList(input);
          }
        });
  }

  private String getUserRecordsAsSingleStringFromThisParticularList(List<User> a_list_of_users) {
    return "i concatenated them or something";
  }

  private class User {
    String a_name_or_something;
  }

}
```

It's a mockup, but I hope it illustrates my point. You'll note I've done a couple of things...
I make sure that users is actually non-null before I ever try to pass it into Transformations.map.
I use the input parameter that map provides. I appreciate that you already know what it refers to which is why your code falls back on using the users field, but thinking about where it comes from and what the Transformations class is trying to do might help you.

In your case, I'd recommend you do this:

```
public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<>();
            // this is the first time the users pointer is not null
            loadUsers();
            prepareUserStringLiveData();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

One final option instead of that would be to go back to your original code and use getUsers() instead of users when you first construct the Transform:

```
public LiveData<String> userStringLiveData = Transformations.map(getUsers(), blah...)
```

It's not the neatest solution, but again - it illustrates why I keep insisting that you're actually passing null into Transformations.map.

Answer (score 1):

in `android:text="@{viewModel.getUserRecords()}` `getUserRecords()` returns a `String`, not a `LiveData` object. What you should is it to bind to a `LiveData<String>` object instead.

E.g.

```
 public LiveData<String> userStringLiveData = Transformations.map(getUsers(), new Function<List<User>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(List<User> input) {
            return getUserRecords();
        }
  });
```

and in your layout `android:text="@{viewModel.userStringLiveData}` . This way, when you post a new value on users, map will be invoked and the UI updated.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea but i'm getting this error: `method map in class Transformations cannot be applied to given types;
required: LiveData<X>,Function<X,Y>
found: MutableLiveData<List<User>>,<anonymous Function<List<String>,String>>
reason: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
inferred: List<String>
equality constraints(s): List<String>,List<User>
where X,Y are type-variables:
X extends Object declared in method <X,Y>map(LiveData<X>,Function<X,Y>)
Y extends Object declared in method <X,Y>map(LiveData<X>,Function<X,Y>)`

Comment: Also why does LiveData<Integer> counter update while app is paused? Isn't LiveData supposed to stop updating when it's not being observed?

Comment: which `Function` did you import?

Comment: android.arch.core.util.Function

Comment: right, in your case input is a `List<User>` not string. I edited the answer

Comment: Now i'm getting     ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference` What does call observeForever?

Comment: android internally. Any chance `users` is null? Could you update the original questions with the changes you did?

Comment: I only added the snippet `public LiveData<String> userStringLiveData = Transformations.map(users, new Function<List<User>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(List<User> input) {
            return getUserRecords();
        }
  });` to MyViewModel class. Other than that, everything is same as before. I can post an edit anyways. I also checked `users` and `user.getValue()` inside `loadUsers()` and they don't return null and they return it before crash

Comment: it is hard to say why it is crashing with NPE. It might be because of the lazy initialization of your `users` object. I saw the edit. It is because of it. Use `getUsers` instead of `users` directly

Comment: Anyway, thanks i got the idea. However `System.out.println()` inside `apply()` is not invoked. Other 2 inside `loadUsers()` gets invoked and does not return **null**. This concept is still new and i haven't been able to find any tutorials so for. In time it will get sorted.

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck with it